# Groupby + Transpose column starting with particular string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **df** like this:

```
ID   Name    Price
1    Fruit   10.5
1    xxx     10.5
1    yyy     8.5
1    Apple    4.2
1    aaa      4.1
1    bbb      0.1
1    Mango    2.1
1    abc      1
1    lmn       
2    Fruit1   7.6  ### and so on for ID 2
```

Above `df` has below properties:

1. The same thing is repeated for `ID 2,3,4` ...and so on
2. For every `ID` the 1st line item will be different. eg `Fruit` and `Fruit1`
3. For every ID there will always be `Apple` some row items and then `Mango`

**Expected Output:**

```
ID  Name   Price   Apple  aaa  bbb  Mango
1   Fruit  10.5    4.2    4.1  0.1  2.1
2   Fruit1 7.6
```

**Problem**:

1.I want a df which keeps the 1st row for every ID

2.Take all the rows starting from `Apple` till `Mango`, do a transpose and put their price value

3.Don't care about the rows like `xxx` or `abc` in my expected output

I know how to `groupby` by ID or `transpose` by a column but can't figure out to `groupby + transpose` only for certain rows.

Comment: It looks like you really need a customized `for` loop instead of using any high-level functions such as `groupby`.

Comment: There are always same number of values from Apple till Mango ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sometimes Pandas methods aren't the answer.

```
seen = set()
result = []
current = None
apple = 'Apple'
mango = 'Mango'
fruit = {apple, mango}

for tup in df.itertuples():
    if tup.ID not in seen:
        result.append({'ID': tup.ID, 'Name': tup.Name})
        current = result[-1]
        seen.add(tup.ID)
    elif mango not in current and (tup.Name in fruit or apple in current):
        current[tup.Name] = tup.Price

d = pd.DataFrame(result)

d

   Apple  ID  Mango    Name   aaa   bbb
0    4.2   1    2.1   Fruit   4.1   0.1
1   40.2   2   20.1  Fruit1  40.1  10.1
```

---

I'll use a fun sorting technique to get things in the correct order.

```
key = lambda x: (x != 'ID', x != 'Name', x != 'Apple', x == 'Mango')
d[sorted(d, key=key)]

   ID    Name  Apple   aaa   bbb  Mango
0   1   Fruit    4.2   4.1   0.1    2.1
1   2  Fruit1   40.2  40.1  10.1   20.1
```

---

#### Experimental

```
def f(id_, d):
    names = d.Name.to_numpy()
    apple = names == 'Apple'
    mango = np.append(False, names[:-1] == 'Mango')
    a = np.logical_or.accumulate(apple)
    m = np.logical_or.accumulate(mango)
    mask = a ^ m
    res = {'ID': id_, 'Name': d.Name.iloc[0], **dict(zip(names[mask], d.Price[mask]))}
    return res

key = lambda x: (x != 'ID', x != 'Name', x != 'Apple', x == 'Mango')
pd.DataFrame([*map(f, *zip(*df.groupby('ID'),))]).pipe(lambda d: d[sorted(d, key=key)])

   ID    Name  Apple   aaa   bbb  Mango
0   1   Fruit    4.2   4.1   0.1    2.1
1   2  Fruit1   40.2  40.1  10.1   20.1
```

---

#### Experiment #2

This isn't perfect as it doesn't guarantee that only things between `'Apple'` and `'Mango'` are kept.

```
def f(d):
    d0 = d.drop('Price', 1).head(1).reset_index(drop=True)
    d1 = d.set_index('Name')[['Price']].tail(-1).T.reset_index(drop=True)
    return d0.join(d1)

d = pd.concat([f(d) for _, d in df.groupby('ID')], ignore_index=True)
i, j = d.columns.get_indexer(['Apple', 'Mango'])

d[['ID', 'Name']].join(d[d.columns[i:j + 1]])

   ID    Name  Apple   aaa   bbb  Mango
0   1   Fruit    4.2   4.1   0.1    2.1
1   2  Fruit1   40.2  40.1  10.1   20.1
```

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194185/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-jezrael

Comment: @piRSquared: Thanks for the detailed Answer!! This works well for above df!! But when I was trying I found there are some more conditions in my Input df like `1. I want Startswith Apple and not equals Apple` .... `2. For every ID there are 2 line items named Mango I want to get from Apple to 1st Mango` .....`3. Elements between Apple and 1st Mango can change`

Comment: Should I ask a new question..or these can be adjusted into this answer only...Looking for your advice here!!